# Print ports with the application using it

Tags: text-processing, awk, netstat

I want to print 2 fields together, all open ports and the application using it. This is my command but it only prints the port numbers and still missing the program field:

```
netstat -lnt -u -p | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.*://' | sort -n | uniq
```

How can I modify this to print also the Program name as in "PID/Program name" will return "java"

A sample of "`netstat -lnt -u -p`" looks like this:

tcp ,       0 ,     0 , 10.194.194.21:36195 ,         0.0.0.0:* ,                   LISTEN , 2969/java

And I want to see only the port number and the program name:

```
 36195 java
```

Comment: @AFSHIN every time you edit last 2 fields disappear from the command output. please be careful

Comment: No, I'm just formatting it, nothing more! nothing going disappear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortened solution:

```
netstat -lpunt | awk -F' +|:+|/' '$5{print $5,$10}' | sort -n
```

- `-F' +|:+|/'` - field separator (space(s), colon(s) or slash)
- `$5` - port number
- `$10` - program name

Comment: thanks it works well, could you explain a bit for future reference?

Comment: @Spring, the main trick here is in field separator, which allows to access the needed fields by its numbers/positions. We can visually determine which fields should be printed

Comment: tnx and how did you calculate the number 10? program name is the 7th field

Comment: @Spring, again, compound field separator will separate the filed containing a potential delimiter into several fields, e.g. `10.194.194.21:36195` will be divided into 2 fields `10.194.194.21` and `36195`

Comment: ok in this case using double "$5" is not really necessary right? I see {print $5,$10} also works

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out the 6th field as well as 4th

This should return what you expected to have. (as I don't know the command result and surely there will be a more efficient way.)

```
netstat -lnt -u -p | awk '{print $4,$6}' | sed 's/.*://' | sort -n | uniq
```

Here is the way you could get the only port and programName (no extra `sed` Is needed and `sort` command can *uniqe* with its `-u` option):

```
netstat -lnt -u -p | awk -F"[,:/]" '{print $5,$NF}'| sort -un
36195  java
```

Comment: @tnx it almost worked but I dont wanna see the pid either, now it looks like this: 2014 2969/java

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: could you print the full command I couldnt make this work

Comment: hmm that prints nothing for me..but RomanPerekhrest answer worked well. Thanks for your time

Comment: thanks, that's maybe because the output is different that you posted in your question,